# apply an xslt function to some nodes from libxml2 in Python

Tags: python, xslt, libxml2

In a python script, I want to aplly the following XSLT functions : normalize-space and translate to some nodes from an libxml2 tree

Can it be done without writing a stylesheet ?

If a stylesheet is needed, what will it look like ?

how to set the context node to a given node from python ?

Comment: in fact it's very easy :D

    
    context = xmlDoc.xpathNewContext()
    extractedContent = context.xpathEval( normalize-space( translate( /html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/h3[1] , '&#160;' , ' ' ) )
    context.xpathFreeContext()


I thought normalize-space and translate could be accessed only from an XSLT engine
I was wrong

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) and [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) are standard XPath functions**, so they can be used in any XPath expression -- without XSLT.

Just use the API for your XPath engine.

Answer (score 0):

in fact it's very easy :D

```
context = xmlDoc.xpathNewContext()
extractedContent = context.xpathEval( normalize-space( translate( /html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/h3[1] , '&#160;' , ' ' ) )
context.xpathFreeContext()
```

I thought normalize-space and translate could be accessed only from an XSLT engine
I was wrong